# Multiple regular expression replacements log4j2 xml pattern tag

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j, log4j2

Hi I am configuring log4j2 via an xml file. I have set up an appender and its is logging properly. I am having issue configuring two regular expressions to replace text in the %message variable of my log.

I am logging messages in my java code like this:

```
logger.info("{ 'name':'person', age:'42' }");
```

I am sending these logs to Kafka and want to replace all { or } with "" and all ' with ".

The current pattern I am using looks like this:

```
<pattern>{ "logTimestamp":"%date{ISO8601}", %replace{%replace{%message{nolookups}}{\\"|\\'|"}{'}}{{|}}{},"host":"${hostname}" }</pattern>
```

However this is not working and I am getting the following parsed message as a result of the replacement:

```
{ "logTimestamp":"2017-03-27T11:11:17,247", %replace}{"}{'},"host":"hostname" }
```

What is the proper way to match and replace two patterns with log4j2 %replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to nest one `%replace` statement inside another.

Try this:

```
%replace{ %replace{%msg}{&apos;}{&quot;} }{\{|\}}{&quot;&quot;}
```

The result is:

```
"" "name":"person", age:"42" ""
```

I hope it helps.